# Unable to filter an array after removing an element in a class method

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, filter

I can't filter my array using a filter function. There is a need to get an updated, filtered array. If I can upgrade it somehow, please let me know what I can change in the code.

```
class Store {
  constructor(items) {
    this._items = items;
  }
  getItems() {
    return this._items;
  }
  addItem(item) {
    this._items.push(item); 
    return this._items;
  }
  removeItem(item) {
    this._items.filter(value => value != item);
    return this._items;
  }
}

let storage = new Store([
  'Cubbage',
  'Garlice',
  'Sauce',
  'Tomato',
]);

let items = storage.getItems(); 
console.table(items);

storage.addItem('banana'); 
console.table(items);

storage.removeItem('Tomato');
console.table(items); //
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method **creates a new array** with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

So, either you need to set the `this._items` like:

```
removeItem(item) {
    this._items = this._items.filter(value => value != item);
    return this._items;
}
```

Or, simply return the `this._items.filter()` method like:

```
removeItem(item) {
    return this._items.filter(value => value != item);
}
```

```js
class Store {
  constructor(items) {
    this._items = items;
  }
  getItems() {
    return this._items;
  }
  addItem(item) {
    this._items.push(item);
    return this._items;
  }
  removeItem(item) {
    this._items = this._items.filter(value => value != item);
    return this._items;
  }
}

let storage = new Store(['Cubbage','Garlice','Sauce','Tomato']);

storage.addItem('banana');
let items = storage.removeItem('Tomato');
console.log(items); //
```

Answer (score 2):

Well `.filter()` doesnt change your array it just creates a new array. you need to assign it to your array.

```
this._items = this._items.filter(value => value != item);
```

To remove a single item you could also use `.splice()`

```
  removeItem(item) {
    this._items.splice(this._items.indexOf(item), 1);
    return this._items;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`.filter` creates a new array, it does not modify the existing one.
 Try this:

```js
class Store {
    constructor(items) {
      this._items = items;
    }
    getItems() {
      return this._items;
    }
    addItem(item) {
      this._items.push(item);
      return this._items;
    }
    removeItem(item) {
      const res =this._items.filter(value => value != item);
      return res;
    }
  }

  let storage = new Store([
    'Cubbage',
    'Garlice',
    'Sauce',
    'Tomato',
  ]);

  let items = storage.getItems();
  console.table(items);

  storage.addItem('banana');
  console.table(items);

  storage.removeItem('Tomato');
  console.table(items);
```